# Simple jquery code does not work

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with the following code, it should find what i type in the search box in yellow.
It does not work, i have included both the jquery and html code. They are not in the same page on my editor, the jquery is in a file called js/ext.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('search_name').keyup(function(){
        search_name = $(this).val();


        $('names li').removeClass('highlight');

        if(jQuery.trim(search_name) != ""){
          $("#names li:contains('"+ search_name +"')").addClass('highlight');

        }

     });
});

<p><input id="search_name" type="text"/></p>
<ul id="names">
    <li>Alex Garrett</li>
    <li>Billy Garrett</li>
    <li>Dale Garrett</li>
    <li>Ashley Garrett</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `$('#search_name')` instead of `$('search_name')` to select by ID.

And actually same problem with `$('names li')`!

Answer (score 1):

Ids in jquery are always preceded by a "#"

```
$('#search_name').keyup(function() {

...
$('#names li').removeClass('highlight');
```